# Nature of optional arguments argparse Python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, argparse, optional-arguments

As I have started to learn argparse module, I try to get my head around optional arguments in Python argparse. I would like to add my own arguments, as I present below:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sense", help = "What you are seeking")
arg = parser.parse_args()

if arg.sense:
    print("42")
```

However, the help doesn't seem to accept the new argument in output:

```
"""python3 file.py -h"""

usage: file.py [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

What surprises me is the fact, that when I copied the code from a tutorial:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.verbose:
    print("verbosity turned on")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

the help changed. Is there a list of possible optional arguments? Am I allowed to create new ones?

Comment: Your code looks good.  I suspect this `file.py` does not really contain that code.  Double check the file editing and saving.

Comment: Hi, I have tried multiple times yesterday to run the code, but only today I managed to force the help to include `sense`. Supposedly PyCharm got tired.

Comment: Posters often have problems providing commandline arguments when working in pycharm.